# How to only keep the columns with same names between two data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames like the following:

```
a<-c(1,3,4,5,6,8)
b<-c(2,3,4,2,6,7)
c<-c(2,5,6,3,5,6)
df1<-data.frame(a,b,c)
d<-c(3,4,5,6,7,8)
e<-c(1,2,3,2,1,1)
c<-c(1,3,4,5,6,2)
df2<-data.frame(d,e,c)



> df1
  a b c
1 1 2 2
2 3 3 5
3 4 4 6
4 5 2 3
5 6 6 5
6 8 7 6
> df2
  d e c
1 3 1 1
2 4 2 3
3 5 3 4
4 6 2 5
5 7 1 6
6 8 1 2
```

I want combine the two data frames,and only keep the columns with the same names. The final data frame should like this:

```
> df3
  c1 c2
1  2  1
2  5  3
3  6  4
4  3  5
5  5  6
6  6  2
```

My real data frames have hundreds columns,so I need codes do this job. Can  anyone help me?

Comment: `cbind(df1[, names(df1) %in% names(df2)],df2[, names(df2) %in% names(df1)])` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out which names belong to both dataframes and then bind them:

```
eqnames <- names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]

df3 <- cbind(df1[eqnames], df2[eqnames])
```

You can then rename the columns:

```
names(df3) <- paste0(names(df3), 1:ncol(df3))
```

Resulting in:

```
> df3
  c1 c2
1  2  1
2  5  3
3  6  4
4  3  5
5  5  6
6  6  2
```

Comment: In case there are multiple matches, the renaming algo could go `paste0(names(df3), rep(1:length(eqnames), length(eqnames)))`